# libgdx - trail effect with particle effect or animation

Tags: animation, libgdx, effect, particles

I'm trying to create a sort of "trail effect" behind my player when it's moving.
Something very similar to the one in this app https://youtu.be/W9ZP1i1CoRo. I don't know which approach could be the best or the easier. Could I use some particle effect? I think I can't since the effect is quite regular and not a kind of cloud or something. 
I would be very happy to do it without dealing with complex animations but if it is the only way please explain to me some basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is using particle effects. it's hard to give more information since every particle effect is rather specific to its' game's needs.

I suggest you take a look at the [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-ParticleEffects). Also, take a look at this helpful [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCLa-rgR_MA). It has a basic usage of the particle effect editor, as well as the usage of `ParticleEffect` objects in `libgdx` code.

Comment: I had already watched the tutorial about particles editor but I can't figure out how to change the basic flame effect to something more "squared" like the one in the video... any tip?

Comment: You can change the image that's the base of the particle effect in the `ParticleEditor`. The image is set under "Emmiter Properties" --> "Image". Usually finding the correct Particle effect for a specific game is done via trying different effects until finding the perfect one.

Comment: In order to emulate the effect that I linked, I think I have a problem with the angle. Changing the angle range the best it can do is a column (90° angle) but I would like a "pointed" shape like a triangle...